# http 406 error with soap request

Tags: java, android, soap, soapui, http-status-code-406

I have created a webservice with soap requests.
now the domain has changed on a different server (metanet).

The problem is that all my soap requests done from my android devices generate a 406 error. also If I try the service with the soapui tool it generates the 406 error.

in the access_log file I see: (when done from soapui)

```
xxx.xx.xxx.xxx - - [27/Jun/2013:14:48:07 +0200] "GET /ws/ HTTP/1.1" 406 1240 "-" "Apache-HttpClient/4.1.1 (java 1.5)"
```

and in the error_log

```
[Thu Jun 27 14:48:07 2013] [error] [client xxx.xx.xxx.xxx] mod_security: Access denied with code 406. Pattern match "(TwengaBot|Voila|MJ12bot|Baiduspider|psbot|Yeti|WebofantBot|WebAlta|Bloglines|Java)" at HEADER("USER-AGENT") [severity "EMERGENCY"] [hostname "xxx.xx"] [uri "/ws/"]
```

I have tried to create a .htaccess file and enter the mime type:

```
AddType application/xml xml
```

Anyone some more ideas?
I guess it could be because of the Pattern match 'Java'? how could I resolve this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Your error log "mod_security: Access denied with code" suggests your server is using [modsecurity](http://www.modsecurity.org/projects/modsecurity/apache/) and it looks like you have a rule to prevent robots/ webcrawlers from "TwengaBot|Voila|MJ12bot|Baiduspider|psbot|Yeti|WebofantBot|WebAlta|Bloglines|Java".

You can change that of course and here are some more useful links for you:

http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/2.5.12/modsecurity2-apache-reference.html

http://www.modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/07-logging.html

http://modsecurity.org/documentation/modsecurity-apache/1.9.3/html-multipage/04-rules.html

http://www.modsecurity.org/projects/modsecurity/index.html

Comment: Hi, thank you very much for your suggestion. Unfortunately, I have no access to modify the mod security. This domain is hosted on a webserver only. I only have access via FTP or Plesk.